# GPT 3.5 giving wrong decimal at 12 s.f

Tags: chatgpt-3.5

Due to a cheating in classroom, I discovered that chat gpt 3.5 gives wrong value of the 12th decimal in $10^{0.2}$ (a seven). GPT 4 gives the right answer with the Wolfram plugin. Why is that? I want to understand why it fails

Comment: How do you make this discovery? Are you using GPT 3.5 by using code written by you, or are you using a third-party app? What is the prompt that you used? What lead you to expect that two different models, one of them using a plug-in, behave the same way?

Comment: It may be due to how floating numbers are stored: https://0.30000000000000004.com/